# Create First Project in QtCreator, problems with kits

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I've just switched to QtCreator for C and C++ developing. I have problem in creating first project, in particular with compiler kits I suppose.
When I go to create a new project, I have the error message that no kits is available.
[image: No valid kits found]
[image: Kits]
[image: Qt Version]

As you can see, I don't know why it is shown that Qt Version is invalid. How could I solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install QtCreator on MAC OS X you can find it in

```
/applications/qt
```

in this folder there is another folder called

```
5.2.1
```

Here there are all the compilers.

So to solve the issue you can either add, in QtCreator options, the path of every qmake.bin file or cut the 5.2.1 folder and paste in

`/Users/YOURNAME/qt`

creating qt folder if it doesn't exist.

**PS:** I've tried to make the directory invisible, but if I do so, I get errors using the second method

Comment: what will its solution for windows

Answer (score 0):

You should first install your C++ compiler. You should also define your compiler in "Compilers" section. If you also want to use Qt you should set the compiler for your kit in the "Kits" section.